# Difference between two means and medians in stata

Tags: stata, difference

I want to export p-value of means and median difference to latex from stata. I tried the code below and it works for p-value of means. However, I dont know how to add the analysis on the difference between medians. Can you please help me with this?

```
eststo control: quietly estpost summarize a b c if treated == 0
eststo treated: quietly estpost summarize a b c if treated == 1
eststo diff: quietly estpost ttest a b c, by(treated) unequal
esttab using means_medians.tex, replace  mlabels("Treated" "Control" "Difference")  
cells("mean(pattern(1 1 0) fmt(2)) sd(pattern(1 1 0 ) fmt(3)) b(star pattern(0 0 1) fmt(2))") label
```

Comment: Various tests have been described as tests for medians, whether loosely or with more justification, and it's up to you to decide which one you want. That's a statistical question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `epctile` that is implemented as a proper estimation commands and returns `e(V)` and the estimation table. (Disregard the ugly output in the first part. I wrote it about 10 years ago for a specific project, but it seems like I have never made it pretty enough for the general use.)

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. epctile mpg, p(50)

Mean estimation                   Number of obs   =         74

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
    __000006 |   -.027027    .058435     -.1434878    .0894338
--------------------------------------------------------------

Percentile estimation
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         p50 |         20        .75    26.67   0.000     18.53003    21.46997
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This command is not on SSC, it is on my page, so to install it, follow the prompts in `findit epctile`.

Comment: Stas: OP wants a test of the difference between two medians.